# How can I get files within the tests in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-packaging

I have the following package structure:

```
.
├── my_app
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── cli.py
│   ├── db.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── setup.py
├── tests
│   ├── data
│   │   └── foobar.gz
│   ├── test_app.py
│   └── test_database.py
└── tox.ini
```

Within `test_app.py`, I do this:

```
import pkg_resources
path = '../tests/data/foobar.gz'
full_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, path)
```

Now I've seen the message:

> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:1145:
>   DeprecationWarning: Use of .. or absolute path in a resource path
>   is not allowed and will raise exceptions in a future release.
> self, resource_name
> ```

What should I do instead?

(I could also change the structure of the package, but I would like to keep the test data within the tests - it is not necessary for running the application)

Comment: In what context are you trying to do this? The problem is, in part, that your `tests` directory is not actually part of the package. This in itself is fine (there are arguments about which way is better but either way is justifiable). So `pkg_resources` is complaining that you're trying to access a file outside the package. If you just want to get a path to a file relative to `test_app.py` all you need is `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data', 'foobar.gz'))`

Comment: Are you saying that I should change the project structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the test resource when passing the test filename to `pkg_resources` you want to use the path from the file with the tests like:

```
import pkg_resources
path = 'data/foobar.gz'
full_path = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, path)
```

With pytest, I also use this pattern in `conftest.py`:

```
@pytest.fixture('session')
def test_data_dir():
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'data')
```

I can the use `os.path.join()` to easily get to any test data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to this problem using `pytest`. Add the following fixture to `conftest.py`. Request this fixture from a test by specifying `resource_file` as an argument to your test. When calling this fixture with a filename (e.g. `resource_file("expected_doc.html")` it will generate a folder structure of the form `resources/path/to/test/test_file_name/test_name/expected_doc.html` and create the resource file if it doesn't exist yet (convenient for finding where the file should go). Finally, the call will return the path to the file. The advantage of this solution is that you don't need to do any path munging in your tests.

Fixture:

```py
@fixture(scope="function")
def resource_file(request):
    test_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    relative_test_file_location = str(request.fspath).removeprefix(test_root).removesuffix(".py").removeprefix("/")
    test_resource_dir = os.path.join(test_root, "resources", relative_test_file_location, request.function.__name__)

    def resolve_and_create_if_missing(filename):
        final_path = os.path.join(test_resource_dir, filename)
        if not os.path.exists(final_path):
            # creating the dir
            os.makedirs(test_resource_dir, exist_ok=True)
            # creating the file
            open(final_path, "a").close()
        return final_path

    return resolve_and_create_if_missing
```

Example test:

```py
def test_something(resource_file):
    resource_filename = resource_file("expected_doc.html")
    # use the file via resource_filename
```

Answer (score -1):

Try os module

```
import os.path

source_folder =  os.getcwd()
path = os.path.join(source_folder, 'data/foobar.gz')
```

Comment: `os.getcwd()` returns your current working directory and will change depending on what directory the user runs it from. It's a bad idea and doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

To get a path relative to your script directory, try to work with the script location itself:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0])
```

You can get the directory containing the script using `os.path.dirname()`:

```
import os
import sys
print(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
```

Then, `os.path.join()` might help to create arbitrary paths:

```
import os
import sys
print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]), "some_subdir"))
```

HTH!